# Extract data from two flat files using a key (phone_no) and print or purge matching records

Tags: perl

Here is another set of my final assignment

This is my final assignment.

I have been given a fixed flat file withemployee list below.

```
Employee (20 bytes) title (20 bytes) Dept (13) phone (14)

example
ABAD, RACHEL PR    CLERK ENGINEERING   ENGR DIST OFC  (818) 374-7538 
ABDULLAH, SOLOM SAFETY ENGR PRESS    VES INSPECTIO   (818) 374-9930  
ABEL, DARLA SR       SAFETY ENG ELEVATORSINSPECTION   (213) 202-9839  
ABRAHAM, TERESA SR MGMT ANALYST II     RES MGMT CUS (213) 482-6766  
ABRAMYAN, DANIEL   INACTIVE            NONE            NONE
ABREU, JAMES       BUILD MECH INSPECTORCODE ENFCMNT   (818) 374-9862 
ACEVEDO CASTRO,    MECH ENGRG ASS      ENGINEERING    (213) 202-9902
ACOSTA, JESUS GEOTECH ENGINEER II INSPECTION GRADING  (213) 482-6967 
AGHAZARIAN, SAKO SRBUILD INSPECTOR     INSPECTION BLDG(213) 482-0372
```

a second file contains only list of phone numbers, which happen to be on the list of employee list.

```
(818) 374-9930
(213) 202-9902
(213) 482-0373
(818) 374-7538
```

If there is a match, I need to extract and printout the entire line (to another file) but for now I am testing check to ensure am able to read the hash. (terminated.dat)

```
!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open PHONELIST, "< PHONELIST.TXT" or die "could not open PHONELIST.TXT\n";
my $phone_no;
while (<PHONELIST>) {
   chomp;
   $phone_no->{$_} = 1;

    print "$phone_no\n";
}
close PHONELIST;

open EMPRECORD, "< EMPRECORD.TXT" or die "could not open EMPRECORD.TXT\n";
while (<EMPRECORD>) {
    chomp;
    my ($phoneKey) = ($_);
    if (defined $phone_no->{$phoneKey}) {
        print STDOUT "$_\n";
  }
}
close EMPRECORD;
```

I am unable to create the hash  or array to read and compare the two files and remove terminated accounts from lists. Please advise what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are reading the whole line from your employee list into the `$phoneKey` variable.
You then need to extract the actual phone number for searching.

I suggest adding:

```
$phoneKey =~ s/.*(\([0-9]+\) [0-9]+\-[0-9]+)$/$1/;
```

or something similar.

Actually, looking at your spec...

```
$phoneKey = substr($_, -13);
```

might be a better choice.

Comment: I prefer to extract rather than modify, and force the number of digits instead of using `+` which can pull in errors.

`m/(\(\d{3}\) \d{3}\-\d{4})/;` then `$phoneKey = $_;`

Comment: Also, `->` are unnecessary, you can simply use $phone_no{$phoneKey}. `->` implies a dereference (which is there, but semantically misleading in the context).